# modify model so that Rails create through parent receives more than parent id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm looking for a way yo share more attributes with the child object from the parent object than just the parent id, and I'm looking to adjust either the parent or child model to do so. For example, creating a kid from a parent would automatically include specific parent attributes

```
@kid = Parent.kids.create()

#=> {parent_id: parent_id, parent_attribute_1: parent_attribute_1, etc...}
```

Comment: generally you dont need to do that as you can always access them using parent. im not sure about your case specifically. one thing you can do is which is the easiest one. that add column to the kids table as well which you want from parent and add use `after_create`  in kid model. which will do is that copy the attributes from the parent and save it in child each time child is created for the parent.

Comment: Why would a `Kid` object have attributes from another model? Or do you mean it has attributes that are set based on the Parent object? Using specifics here would help.

Comment: @Athar The only problem with the after_create is that I am dealing with creating a lot of kid objects at a time, and I am concerned about the extra time it would take to locate the parent object and pull the attributes that way

Comment: @eirikir I mean it has attributes set that are the exact same as the parent model, so for example, if parent = {attribute_1: attribute_1} child would have {attribute_1: attribute_1}

Comment: I dont think that it will take too much as there should be index on parent_id in kid which will obviously less time taking and once object is there no time for pulling attributes. but more imp thing is if you know they are going to be alot of kids object that are going to be created then you should also think of space that they are going to share extra when same thing is already present in Parent. still you know the schema and requirement well.

Comment: @user3155734 Do you need to set those attributes, or can you just access them via the associated parent object? Setting the attributes in two places violates [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principles and presents maintenance problems: what happens if the attribute changes on the parent object? Does it change on the child as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way would probably be to have a separate builder class which encapsulates the copying logic. Eg:

```
# kidbuilder.rb
class KidBuilder
  def self.create_kid_for(parent)
    child = parent.kids.new
    child.attr = parent.attr # repeat as necessary
    child.save
    child
  end
end 

# controller
@child = KidBuilder.create_kid_for(parent)
```

An alternative would be using a `before_create` callback on `kid`, but this is probably a bad idea as it forces creation of every `kid` to be coupled to `parent`.

On a side note, having to maintain the same data attributes in multiple places is very painful. Consider using [delegate](http://pivotallabs.com/rails-delegates-are-even-more-useful-than-i-knew/) if `kid` will not be modifying the attributes from `parent`.

Comment: Thanks. For me this is a workable answer! I'm going to wait to see if anyone comes up with anything else that is more natural, but if nothing else comes up, you have solved it